# WordPress documentation - WP_Query arguments

Tags: wp-query, documentation

I've been looking for a list all WP_Query arguments.

This looks obvious, but http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query isn't helpful at all, "post_type" is mentioned only in an example, and arguments like "posts_per_page" aren't even there.

Comment: The `WP_Query` page is purposely written in that way to detail the methods of the `WP_Query class`, `query_posts` lists all the possible args for use with queries, `query_posts` is just a wrapper/convenience function for the main `$wp_query->query()` object. `$wp_query->query()` is also just a wrapper for the `$wp_query->get_posts()` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) is what you're looking for.

(You're right to look for it on the class documentation...i think the reason why it's on `query_posts()` is because that (and `get_posts()`) is meant to be the primarily used function to get posts.)

Answer (score 4):

Hi **@Wordpressor:**

The arguments for `WP_Query()` are documented on the `query_posts()` page on the Codex:

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts

And for WordPress 3.1 you can also find the most complete documentation for the `WP_Query` args on lines [1872 through 2705](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1/wp-includes/query.php#L1860) of `/wp-includes/query.php`. :-)

-Mike